# Weird Unexpected token error messages from babel

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx, babeljs

All of a sudden today, the following code began producing Unexpected token error pointing at the "return" keyword.

```
const func = props => {
    return props.x && props.y ?
        <view1 {...props} /> :
        <view2 {...props} /> 
};
```

When I removed the "return" keyword, the parser points at the last semicolon with an error message of unterminated JSX contents.

My webpack config looks like this:

```
var webpack = require( 'webpack' );

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        './src/index.jsx'
    ],


module: {
        loaders:[{
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'react-hot!babel'
        }]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './webpack_html',
        hot: true
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ]
};
```

What could be causing this error?

Comment: Please include the full error and enough of a snippet to reproduce the problem: https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=react&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&playground=true&code=const%20func%20%3D%20props%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20props.x%20%26%26%20props.y%20%3F%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cview1%20%7B...props%7D%20%2F%3E%20%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cview2%20%7B...props%7D%20%2F%3E%20%0A%7D%3B&stage=0

Comment: If I had to take a stab in the dark, somewhere above the function you posted, you have a JSX element that is an opening tag either without a closing tag, or that was supposed to be self-closing but you left off the `/` in the tag end.

Comment: @loganfsmyth thank you, there was an unterminated div in view2 component. The error message was at the component using the view2 instead of in view2 which was the source of my head scratching. Please put in your official answer and I will accept it.